# implement the star rating in drupal without using the fivestar module

Tags: php, drupal

Is there any other way to implement a star rating system in drupal without the use of the fivestar module?

Comment: You mean other than writing your own?

Comment: Yes, what i am looking for is a jquery package that implements this

Comment: Why don't you want to use the fivestar module?

Comment: We need to know what specifically you want to avoid in the fivestar module before we can recommend alternatives...

Answer (score 2):

Using [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+rating) or any other search engine you may find a jQuery plugin to handle the client-side of stars rating. But they will always need something server-side to retrieve and store the score of your rated things. So you will have to [create a custom module](http://drupal.org/node/361112) ton handle this part. The [Voting API](http://drupal.org/project/votingapi) module may help you there. But as its name implies, this is just an API for others module to build on.

If your issue is actually that you are not happy with the looks and feels of the fivestar module, you may solve it by using themeing and by [providing your own widget set](http://drupal.org/node/234391).